# How can I find the leaderboard position of a user based on the amount of points they have using SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my database I have a profile table which includes the following columns:

`Id`, `profilename`,`points`,`lastupdated`

Users can be put into the profile table more than once, and for the leaderboard I use the value of the max(`lastupdated`) column.

Below I have SQL code to try and determine someones leaderboard position, and it works except for 1 small problem.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  `profilename` )
FROM  `profiletable`
WHERE  `points` >= integer
```

If two people have the same points, then they have the same leaderboard position, but this makes the count function work in a way that I didnt not intend.

For example:

```
position 1: profilename john points 500
position 2: profilename steve points 300
position 2: profilename alice points 300
position 4: profilename ben points 200
```

When I run the SQL query with Integer being set to john's points, I get a return value of 1 from the count function, but when I run the SQL query for steve or alice, instead of getting 2, I get 3.

I have also tried using the logic `points > integer` but this returns 1 for steve or alice.

How can I modify the SQL query so that the correct leaderboard position is returned by the count?

Comment: When creating the list, use MySQL to return the list, and PHP to number the positions. Regarding your query, since you have ```where `points` >= 300```, you get 3 because john is included in the count. as well as steve and alice.

Answer (score 1):

Use greater than in the where clause and add 1 to the count:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  `profilename` ) + 1
FROM  `profiletable`
WHERE  `points` > integer
```

Update:

If you need to take into the updated time field as well, then first you need to get the record associated with the last update time:

```
SELECT COUNT(p1.`profilename` ) + 1
FROM  `profiletable` p1
LEFT JOIN `profiletable` p2 ON p1.profilename=p2.profilename
    and p1.lastupdated<p2.lastupdated
WHERE  p1.`points` > integer and p2.profilename is null
```